# CUDA Compute Capability 2.0. Global memory access pattern

Tags: cuda

From CUDA Compute Capability 2.0 (Fermi) global memory access works through 768 KB L2 cache. It looks, developer don't care anymore about global memory banks. But global memory is still very slow, so the right access pattern is important. Now the point is to use/reuse L2 as much as possible. And my question is, how? I would be thankful for some detailed info, how L2 works and how should I organize and access global memory if I need, for example, 100-200 elements array per thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

L2 cache helps in some ways, but it does not obviate the need for coalesced access of global memory.  In a nutshell, coalesced access means that for a given read (or write) instruction,  individual threads in a warp are reading (or writing) adjacent, contiguous locations in global memory, preferably that are aligned as a group on a 128-byte boundary.  This will result in the most effective utilization of the available memory bandwidth.

In practice this is often not difficult to accomplish.  For example:

```
int idx=threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
int mylocal = global_array[idx];
```

will give coalesced (read) access across all the threads in a warp, assuming `global_array` is allocated in an ordinary fashion using cudaMalloc in global memory.  This type of access makes 100% usage of the available memory bandwidth.

A key takeaway is that memory transactions ordinarily occur in 128-byte blocks, which happens to be the size of a cache line.  If you request even one of the bytes in a block, the entire block will be read (and stored in L2, normally).  If you later read other data from that block, it will normally be serviced from L2, unless it has been evicted by other memory activity.  This means that the following sequence:

```
int mylocal1 = global_array[0];
int mylocal2 = global_array[1];
int mylocal3 = global_array[31];
```

would all typically be serviced from a single 128-byte block.  The first read for `mylocal1` will trigger the 128 byte read.  The second read for `mylocal2` would normally be serviced from the cached value (in L2 or L1) not by triggering another read from memory.  However, if the algorithm can be suitably modified, it's better to read all your data contiguously from multiple threads, as in the first example.  This may be just a matter of clever organization of data, for example using Structures of Arrays rather than Arrays of structures.

In many respects, this is similar to CPU cache behavior.  The concept of a cache line is similar, along with the behavior of servicing requests from the cache.

Fermi L1 and L2 can support write-back and write-through.  L1 is available on a per-SM basis, and is configurably split with shared memory to be either 16KB L1 (and 48KB SM) or 48KB L1 (and 16KB SM).  L2 is unified across the device and is 768KB.

Some advice I would offer is to not assume that the L2 cache just fixes sloppy memory accesses.  The GPU caches are much smaller than equivalent caches on CPUs, so it's easier to get into trouble there.  A general piece of advice is simply to code as if the caches were not there.  Rather than CPU oriented strategies like cache-blocking, it's usually better to focus your coding effort on generating coalesced accesses and then possibly make use of shared memory in some specific cases.  Then for the inevitable cases where we can't make perfect memory accesses in all situations, we let the caches provide their benefit.

You can get more in-depth guidance by looking at some of the available [NVIDIA webinars](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars).  For example, the [Global Memory Usage & Strategy webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/globalmemoryusage_june2011.mp4) (and [slides](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GlobalMemory.pdf)  ) or the [CUDA Shared Memory  & Cache webinar](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/sharedmemoryusage_july2011.mp4) would be instructive for this topic.  You may also want to read the [Device Memory Access section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html).

Comment: Adding to this excellent answer, post-Fermi hardware has an additional, dedicated read-only L1 (the same size as the normal read-write L1). Which means that if there was ever a reason to pay attention to pay attention to such "minor details", it's now.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Nice answer but I have a question regarding coalescent read. For coalescent read of global memory we have to use `__syncthreads();`. In the above example `int local1 = global_array[idx];` would be followed by the `__syncthreads();`. The question is, if i have multiple arrays like `int local1 = global_array1[idx]; int local2 = global_array2[idx]; int local3 = global_array3[idx];` will I have coalescent read with a single `__syncthreads();` after all these definitions? Thanks.

Comment: coalesced reads and `__syncthreads()` have nothing to do with each other.